# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Проблема, во-первых, в том, что **национализировать и, во-вторых**, как управлять национализированным.*

Нужно ли ставить запятую перед союзом "и"? По идее, она не нужна, так как оба придаточных относятся в одному слову ("в том"). Но с толку сбивают "во-первых" и "во-вторых", поэтому я сомневаюсь насчет запятой перед "и": нужна или не нужна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вводные слова можно изъять из предложения (они не влияют на остальные знаки препинания и обособляются независимо от них): **Проблема в том, что национализировать и как управлять национализированным.**

Это однородные придаточные, связанные одиночным союзом И, поэтому **запятая не нужна**.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно согласна с предыдущим ответом.  Я вижу здесь два однородных члена предложения, связанных союзом "и".  Запятая здесь не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, стилистически предложение неверно. Что нациализировать и как управлять — трудные вопросы, которые требуют ответа. Неверно употреблено слово "проблема".

Вариант правки:

**Проблема, во-первых, в отсутствии четких критериев национализации и, во-вторых, в неумении управлять национализированным.**

Вводные слова *во-первых* и *во-вторых* выделяются запятыми. *В отсутствии* и *в неумении* — однородные члены предложения, запятая перед союзом *и* не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В будущем в своих вопросах всегда буду помечать, что эта цитата спикера, которую я не могу переиначить. В данном случае тоже важно было сохранить точность цитаты.